# Proof verification: An arrow which is monic under a faithful functor is itself monic

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, functors, monomorphisms

**Context:**

To introduce some symbols and such, what I'm seeking to prove is this:

> Let $F$ be a faithful functor. Suppose $F(f)$ is a monic arrow. Show $f$ is monic.

This came up as part of a class assignment recently, tied to an introduction to category theory as we began to introduce free objects. I have an attempt ready, but I have a slight feeling that something's wrong with it. I can't really pin it down on *what*, it's just a lurking feeling; alternatively, I could be overthinking.

Any thoughts?

---

**My Attempt at a Proof:**

Let $F : \scr{C} \to \scr{D}$ be a faithful functor. Let us also have arrows $g,h : A \to B$ and $f : B \to C$, where $A,B,C,f,g,h \in \scr C$. Further, let $F(f)$ be monic and let $f \circ g = f \circ h$.

Since $F$ is faithful, it is injective on the hom-sets of $\scr C$. Thus,

$$F(f \circ g) = F(f \circ h) \tag 1$$

Since $F$ is a functor, it preserves composition: thus,

$$F(f \circ g) = F(f) \circ F(g) = F(f) \circ F(h) = F(f \circ h) \tag 2$$

Since $F(f)$ is monic, $(2)$ yields

$$F(f) \circ F(g) = F(f) \circ F(h) \implies F(g) = F(h) \tag 3$$

Again since $F$ is faithful, $(3)$ yields

$$F(g) = F(h) \implies g = h \tag 4$$

Thus, since our assumptions $F$ is faithful, $F(f)$ is monic, and $f \circ g = f \circ h$ imply $g = h$ we can conclude $f$ is monic.

Comment: Looks good to me. The argument was essentially $f \circ g = f \circ h \implies F(f) \circ F(g) = F(f) \circ F(h) \implies F(g) = F(h) \implies g = h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it seems (at this time) the consensus is that this is indeed correct as an approach (though these days I would probably phrase it a little differently).

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*